# Pourquoi devrait-on utiliser 'lavent' dans cette phrase ?

Tags: verbes

J'ai suivi un cours particulier et l'enseignante m'a demandé :

> Qui lave vos chiens ?

J'ai répondu :

> Il n'y a personne qui les lave.

Elle m'a corrigé avec :

> Il n'y a personne qui les lavent.

parce que le verbe "laver" doit s'accorder avec "les" mais que si je disais

> Il n'y a personne qui lave mes chiens.

ce serait correct.

J'ai pensé à "lave" parce que c'est "qui" ou "ne personne" qui "lave".

Est-ce incorrect ?

Peut-être ai-je troublé mon enseignante avec ce que j'ai essayé de dire ?

Comment: Si ta prof t'a indiqué qu'il fallait accorder le verbe avec "les", je sugérerais de changer de prof... Dieu sait combien de telles bêtises elle va sortir à l'avenir.

Comment: In any language, there are two kinds of knowledge: intuitive knowledge and analytical knowledge. Native speakers may be counted on for intuitive knowledge but not analytical knowledge. This is especially true in French, where many grammatical nuances can't be distinguished by ear — here personne(s) and lave(nt). Unfortunately, I find it's common for the teacher of a language course to have only one of these types of knowledge, especially at lower levels. Either they come by the language through native fluency (intuitive) or through hard study (analytical), and the other kind is a blind spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un verbe s'accorde avec son sujet grammatical (ici l'antécédent de *qui* qui est *personne*), pas avec son complément. La forme correcte est donc bien :

> Il n'y a personne qui les lave.

comme on dit

> Il n'y a personne qui les prend.

et pas

> Il n'y a personne qui les <s>prennent</s>.

En revanche, ce sera au pluriel s'il y a plusieurs personnes :

> Il y a trois personnes qui les lavent.

y compris à la forme négative :

> Il n'y a pas de personnes qui les lavent.

Une façon idiomatique de contourner ce problème est de dire :

> Il n'y a personne pour les laver.

Comment: Merci!  Pour les corrections et la réponse. Je sentais ma réponse originale était correcte, mais je n'ai pas voulu disputer!  Peut-être je devrais en discuter à nouveau avec elle cette semaine, pour comprendre ce qu'elle a essayé dire?   Peut-être en engalis donc il n'y a pas malentendus!

Comment: Pour éviter la confusion avec le subjonctif homophone au pluriel, on pourrait prendre FAIRE : *il n'y a personne qui les fait*  vs *il n'y a personne qui les font* .

Comment: Je ne sais pas encore le subjonctif! :D

Answer (score 0):

Évidemment, si le verbe principal est au participe passé et que l'auxiliaire est une forme du verbe 'avoir', alors le participe s'accorde avec un complément d'objet direct si celui-ci le précède et donc on aurait dans ce cas :

Il les a lavés ou Il les a lavées (selon que 'les' fait référence à un nom masculin ou féminin).

Et pour reprendre deux de tes exemples :

Personne ne les a lavé(e)s.

Il y a quelques personnes qui les avaient lavé(e)s.

Comment: Oui, c'est vrai! Mais ma confusion venait de l'utilisation de <<lavent>> au lieu de <<lave>>.  Merci pour votre commentaire, les règles d'objet direct précédentes sont toujours bonnes à réviser! Particulièrement pour moi :D